# Can I configure connect-pg-simple to have SSL on?

Tags: postgresql, session, heroku

I'm running a Postgres DB and a node app on Heroku. When I try to do

```
app.use(session({
  store: new pgSession({
    conString: process.env.DATABASE_URL
  }),
  secret: 'my-super-secret-session',
  resave: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
}));
```

I get a complaint: `error: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "1.2.3.4", user ,myuser", database "mydb", SSL off`

I assume I need to tell `connect-pg-simple` to use SSL somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not able to edit `pg_hba.conf`, because you're using a service like heroku, try this.

All you have to do is replace `conString` with `conObject` and specify a `connectionString` and `ssl` options.

```
app.use(session({
  store: new pgSession({
    conObject: {
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: true,
    },
  }),
  secret: 'my-super-secret-session',
  resave: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
  }
}));
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, however, after applying it, I am now getting 

`Failed to prune sessions: self signed certificate`

. I am using Heroku postgres

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an entry in the pg_hba.conf to allow your connection.

Example:

```
vi $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf
host    all             all             1.2.3.4/32           md5
```

After saving this config file you will need to reload it by issuing a config reload command:

```
pg_ctl reload
```

Then retry the connection.

Comment: It's simpler to add the ?ssl=true parameter to the end of the connection string, as explained in these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301722/ssl-for-postgresql-connection-nodejs