# NodeJS encrypted connection string to Postgres

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am learning NodeJS by building a JWT server.  Basically I want to authorize users against credentials in a PostgreSQL database.  I am considering node-postgres, passport, pg to connect with PostgreSQL but I have not found anyway to store my connection values encrypted.  Ideally I would store them in a properties file so I can change them per environment.

Most examples I see do something like:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "postgres://YourUserName:YourPassword@localhost:5432/YourDatabase";
```

Can someone help show me how to encrypt and use my credentials so I don't have to hard code the plain values in my source?

Comment: Appreciate this is an old answer; mostly writing this for posterity. Putting credentials in source code like this is usually a bad idea, often a very bad one. Pulling them in from the deployment environment gives you more granular access control and operational flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to exist npm packages for this already. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/secure-conf. Seems to fulfill your needs.

Please note, that you should also secure your Connection to the DB using SSL. See [SSL for PostgreSQL connection nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301722/ssl-for-postgresql-connection-nodejs) for a Solution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and awesome answer - will start on that now!

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

if you use sequelize to connect postgres

const sequelize = new Sequelize("DB", usrname, password, {
   host: "/var/run/postgresql",
        dialect: "postgres",
        });

NB: get the host string from your  pgsl db might be different //